# Smooth approximation of BV functions, Proof clarification

Tags: calculus, geometry, analysis, geometric-measure-theory, bounded-variation

Im reading Evans&Gariepy book measure theory and fine properties of functions second edition. I have a question about the proof of theorem 5.3 that I don't understand.

The theorem states that for a function $f \in BV(U)$ there are functions $f_k \in BV(U)\cap C^\infty(U)$
such that $f_k \to f$ in $L^1$ and  $\|Df_k\|(U) \to \|Df\|(U)$. In the proof they definte the sets
$$
U_k =\left\{x \in U: \text{dist}(x,\partial U) > \frac{1}{m+k}\right\} \cap B(0,m+k) $$
where $m,k$ are positive integers
and define
$$V_k = V_{k+1}\setminus V_{k-1} $$
and it is agreed that $U_0 = \emptyset$.

We can see that any element of $U$ is contained at most in 3 sets $V_k$, but What I don't understand is why this implies that
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \|Df\|(V_k) \leq 3 \|Df\|(U-U_1) $$

I know that $\cup_{k=2}^\infty V_k = U\setminus U_1$ but  I don't see why the last inequality is true. Any help is appreciated.